Main cached query called by other async methods
I have a main sub-query shared by multiple queries:
private List<MyCustomClass> Foo() 
{
    var t = _ctx.Table1
                .Where(...)
                .Select(s => new MyCustomClass { ... })
                .ToList();

    // IMemoryCache the result here 
 
    return t;
}

Ideally, this method could be sync or async, it's not important if it works.
I would like to use the results of it, as I said, in more async query:
public Task<List<OtherClassA>> MyAmazingMethodA() 
{
    return await Foo()
                    .Where(..A..)
                    .GroupBy(..A..)
                    .Select(s => new OtherClassA { ... })
                    .ToListAsync();
}

...

public Task<List<OtherClassZ>> MyAmazingMethodZ() 
{
    return await Foo()
                    .Where(..Z..)
                    .GroupBy(..Z..)
                    .Select(s => new OtherClassZ { ... })
                    .ToListAsync();
 }

Is it possible to do something like this?
Thanks a lot.

Instead of returning a List you should return an IQueryable, which can then be further composed, or you can use ToListAsync, on the return value.
private IQueryable<MyCustomClass> GetFooQueryable()
{
    var t = _ctx.Table1
                .Where(...)
                .Select(s => new MyCustomClass { ... });
    return t;
}

Note that the result is not cached anywhere, it will be re-queried from the database each time. This will probably be more efficient in your case, because you don't actually need these results, only the composition with other queries. You can rely on the database itself to do caching etc.

I've just updated my question so my goal could be more clear now. Tnx

Sorry I'm not sure what you've added that changes what I said. You shouldn't ToList something if you don't actually need all that data. The database is perfectly capable of doing its own caching.

After a fair amount of sweat I have a solution, I don't know if it is THE solution but it works like a charm.
Thanks to Amir Popovich suggestion, I used the nuget package System.Linq.Async.
Meanwhile Foo() method will be async and chaceable:
private async Task<List<MyCustomClass>> Foo() 
{
    var t = await _ctx.Table1
                           .Where(...)
                           .Select(s => new MyCustomClass { ... })
                           .ToListAsync();

    // can IMemoryCache the result here 
 
    return t;
}

note that Foo is not queryable but it materializes the result before returning.
And so now it can be called from other methods:
public Task<List<OtherClass>> MyAmazingMethod() 
{
    var tmp = await Foo();

    var t = await tmp
                    .Where(...)
                    .GroupBy(...)
                    .Select(s => new OtherClass { ... })
                    .ToAsyncEnumerable()                  //this is the magic!
                    .ToListAsync();
  
    return t;
}

I hope it can be useful to you.
Thanks.

Yes, it is possible.
You can update the sync method to this
public List<OtherClass> MyAmazingMethod()
{
    var fooResult = Foo();

    return fooResult
        .Where(...)
        .GroupBy(...)
        .Select(s => new OtherClass { ... })
        .ToList();
}

